# discord.py listen for and send private message

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot in Python that listens for private messages and then replies.

The way I want it to be designed is that the user sends a command to the bot "!token", the bot then iterates over an Array. And if the discordID of the message sender is in the list, the bot then returns a token related to that discordID. If the discordID is not there then it replies with "No token".

Quite new to Python. I have looked through documentations and cant seem to find what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a place to start. Try here: https://docs.python.org/3/

Comment: In this case i am trying to use discord.py, not Python by itself. So was just looking for a little headstart :)

Comment: Welcome to discord.py development. Here is the newest documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that you're new to discord.py and Python in general I've written out a bit more than I generally would without an example of what you've tried yourself.

The way this is set up now it'll only listen to "!token" You can take this code and add your own commands to it by following the same schematic. I've also left the part where you store the tokens out because you weren't clear on how you wanted that. I'd read up on [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to store those though.

As Patrick Haughs mentioned you can use the check [commands.dm_only](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) to make sure this will only run in private messages and not in any servers your bot might connect to.

```
from discord.ext import commands

idList =[IDS]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

runtoken = TOKEN

@bot.command()
async def token(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in idList:
        await ctx.author.send("Token")
    else:
        await ctx.author.send("No token")

bot.run(runtoken)
```

Comment: I'd add the [`commands.dm_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) check to restrict the command to DMs

Comment: Yeah I was in a bit of a rush when I wrote this, should have probably included some explanation as well. It's a good recommendation though so I'll add it in with my explanation.